# C++ Default and Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

Option 1 (BAD):

```
    Point p1(); 
    Point p2 = p1; //error: conversion from 'Point()' to non-scalar type 'Point' requested
```

Option 2:

```
    Point p1 = Point(); 
    Point p2 = p1; //Ok
```

Option 3:

```
    Point p1; 
    Point p2 = p1; //Ok
```

Why is the first one not working and the other two do?

I thought that everything would behave the same, for this example I didn't implement anything in
`Class Point{}`
I don't understand why there is a difference between the default constructors

***** EDIT:*****
Other constructors would have worked, for example.

```
    Point p1(4); 
    Point p2 = p1; // will work
```

So I guess only default Constractor is a problem?

Comment: How would you declare a function with no parameters that returns a `Point` and is called `p1` ? `Point p1();`. Its a function not an object of type `Point`

Comment: `Point p1();` does not do what you think it does. This declares a function named `p1` that takes no parameters and returns a `Point`. Welcome to C++. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

Comment: Because if it wasn't default constractor I could have done:
```
    Point p1(4); 
    Point p2 = p1; //Ok
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hq1dGoEje

Comment: no, its not only with the default constructor as eg in the duplicate